# How are tmp file names in php generated ?

Tags: php, file-upload, temporary-files

How are tmp file names (uploaded) in php generated? What is the mechanism of it? Can I rely that they are always unique?

The problem is that I want to copy all uploaded files into one const directory and I'm not sure if tmp names will reoccur in the history of my server running.

Comment: don't use the internal temp names, create your own with the likes of [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

Comment: the temp names are just that... temp. you shouldn't rely on them being unique for the life of the server, just for the duration of handling the upload.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately the temporary filenames generated by PHP use the function [`mkstemp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkstemp.html) / [`mktemp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/mktemp.html) which guarantees the filename will be unique.  If a filename that it generates already exists, it will try a number of times to generate a non-existent filename.

On Windows, PHP uses [`GetTempFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which makes the same guarantee about uniqueness.

In either case, if the functions can't return a unique filename, they return an error value and PHP would not return a filename to you at all.